# general formula for inserting a row between every row of data

Tags: google-sheets

I do not want to use `Google App Script` for this solution.

so I have a column of data say, input:

```
a
b
c
```

I want to output:

```
a

b

c
```

just add a row between each row on the output using a general formula `=somefunction(A1:A)`

Comment: What about using a custom function (written in GAS, but used as any built-in formula)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=if(isODD(row()),index($A$1:$A,(row()+1)/2,1),"")
```

index formula can be used to access any row, column from a data array($A1:$A). 
Row() gives the row of the current of the cell. (row()+1)/2 basically makes sure we get the index in order in every other row.